# Как правильно запустить тест в HP ALM по REST API?

Tags: jenkins, автоматизация, нагрузочное-тестирование

Всем привет!

Стоит задача автоматизировать сборку сценария и его запуск через HP ALM в Jenkins
Все, что пришло в голову, это делать задачу при помощи REST API и, допустим, Java, но и тут пока плохо понимаю, как и к чему подступиться
Пока могу только дергать список уже существующих тестов. Но этого недостаточно

Загуглить не предлагать. Уже ни один раз это было сделано

Возможно, у кого-то из вас есть в закромах хороший ресурс (помимо документации) или личный опыт, которым будет не жалко поделиться, то очень прошу помощи

Answer (score 0):

Через REST API - никак, к сожалению (версия 12.55). Только через старое OTA.

Есть еще плагин для Jenkins, который умеет запускать тесты из HP ALM, называется [Bumblebee HP ALM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bumblebee+HP+ALM+Plugin), но для него нужен [Bumblebee](https://www.agiletestware.com/bumblebee)-сервер (платный).

Disclaimer: Я занимаюсь разработкой Bumblebee